# Обьявление структур друг в друге

Tags: c, структуры

Есть две структуры-типа

```
typedef struct edict_s {
    ...
    entvars_t v;
} edict_t;

typedef struct entvars_s {
    ...
    edict_t *u;
} entvars_t;
```

При компиляции разумеется ругается на то что структура entvars_t незадекларирована, как правильно дать понять компилятору что она будет дальше в коде задекларирована?
Пробовал так `typedef struct entvars_s entvars_t;` но не помогло.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А если так?

```
//struct edict_s; // Как правильно подсказывает @Abyx, даже это не нужно

typedef struct entvars_s {
    ...
    struct edict_s *u;
} entvars_t;

typedef struct edict_s {
    ...
    entvars_t v;
} edict_t;
```

Comment: @Abyx: Точно, запамятовал.

Comment: Спасибо, так работает

Comment: @Виталий: Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 0):

Я обычно объявляю структуры и их типы в верху заголовочных файлов, вроде такого:

```
struct element;
struct list;
typedef struct element *Element;
typedef struct list *List;
```

А сами структуры описываю там, где посчитаю логически нужным.

```
struct list {
    Element Head, Tail;
};
struct element {
    List Home;
    Element Next;
    int Value;
};
```

На мой взгляд, так весьма удобно.